# Better to use a Static method or Object for a Logger in PHP?

Tags: php

I have a very simple Logger class below, my goal is to make log function calls and write the data to a log file but to only make 1 write per page no matter how many times I call the log function

```
session_start();
class JD{
    static private $log = array();

    public function __construct(){  }

    // Simple logger
    // usage JD::log('debug', 'MySQLi Database Driver Initialized');
    public static function log($mode, $message){
        self::$log[] = '[' .$mode. '] = ' .$message. '\r\n';
        $_SESSION['jdlog'] = self::$log;

    }
}
```

testing

```
JD::log('debug', 'MySQLi Database Driver Initialized');
JD::log('debug2', 'MySQLi Database Driver Initialized');
JD::log('debug3', 'MySQLi Database Driver Initialized');
JD::log('debug4', 'MySQLi Database Driver Initialized');
JD::log('debug5', 'MySQLi Database Driver Initialized');
JD::log('debug6', 'MySQLi Database Driver Initialized');
print_r($_SESSION['jdlog']);
```

Ok based on that simple code above, it would appear that it is probably better to just use the static method like I did but I am wanting to write the array of log messages to a file or somewhere else, so with my current method above, it would have to write to a file on every single function call, which defeats the purpose of me saving each call into an array.

If I make it a regular class object then I can simply instantiate my object, make my log function calls as needed, then make 1 write at the end of my page by calling another function that will write the array to file, I can also do away with saving to session.

How would you do something simple like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write a destructor method to handle the file writing when the script execution ends.

Comment: Hey that's a good Idea I have never had an excuse to use a destructor, thanks

Answer (score 0):

I definitely would not trust session functionality to house log data as it is volatile in nature, especially if your are logging critical messages. You may want to look at the [Zend_Log](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.log.overview.html) code for ideas.

To be honest, I don't think it would be a good idea to store many and write once, in case a script is abruptly halted and the write never occurs.

Comment: You can write your log messages in a register_shutdown_function, so they get saved when the script is terminated.

Comment: @djot: Does it even make sense to implement this approach? If a verbose php script runs as a daemon, it will never terminate, so then the array approach the OP is suggesting would result in very large arrays, and anyone trying to tail the log file expecting to see the messages wouldn't end up seeing anything.

Comment: From what I undestand, in this case it's a script triggered by an HTTP server, so `register_shutdown_function()` (being the procedural alternative for my suggestion) makes a perfect sense. There are not many ways to get around it really: a) httpd/server crashes; b) a SIGTERM signal is intentionally sent to the httpd process; c) PHP syntax error (in this case, the script will never run anyway); and d) a fatal runtime error; In the last one - you'll get a standard PHP error logged, and for the rest - you can't guarantee anything anyway.

Comment: @Narf: Agreed. What I am trying to convey is that a store many, write once solution is not the best idea for logging. IMO, it should be anytime a log call is made, to write the log.